Sandwiching ellipses between planar convex bodies
Let $K$ and $L$ be planar convex bodies which are not ellipses. Does there exist an affine image $K'$ of $K$ such that

$K' \subset L$
No ellipse $E$ satisfies $K' \subset E \subset L$

I am also interested in the variant where $K$ and $L$ are centrally symmetric, and $K'$ is required to be a linear image of $K$.

Is this true for, say, a triangle and a near-circle?

The answer is positive if $K$ is a triangle. Assume without loss of generality that the ellipse of maximal area inside $L$ is a disk $D$. If $K$ is any equilateral triangle inscribed in $D$, the only ellipse sandwichable between $K$ and $L$ is the disk $D$ (since the ellipse of minimal area containing $K$ is $D$). Since $L$ is not a disk, it is possible to choose the triangle $K$ such that one vertex lies in the interior of $L$, and now if we move away that vertex to enlarge the area of $K$, we obtain a configuration as required.

Does this also work for non-equilateral triangles?

Yes. Up to affine bijection, there is only one triangle.

Yes, but you seemingly need to turn a triangle inscribed in an ellipse into an equilateral one in such a way that this ellipse becomes a circle, no?

I'm not sure I understand your point. The argument is: if $K$ a triangle and if $L$ is a non-ellipse, it is possible to find affine images $K'$ and $L'$ such that any ellipse containing $K'$ has a larger area than any ellipse contained in $L'$.

@GuillaumeAubrun It seems that the same idea works in larger generality. If we assume that $D$ is the largest area ellipse in $L$ and the smallest area ellipse containing $K$, the argument won’t work only if any rotation of $K$ contains points on the boundary of $D$  which lie on the boundary of $L$, and their convex hull contains the center of $D$. In this case, $K$ or $L$ should have circular segments on $\partial D$ of nonzero measure; maybe some different argument could finish this case?

I agree that the idea works in some generality, but I'm missing arguments to cover remaining cases.

What about the opposite case: Let $L$ be the convex hull of a disc together with a point outside the disc but very close to it, and let $K$ be the intersection of a disc with a half-space which contains almost all but not all of the disc. Then can we squeeze $K$ ins such a way that it lies in $L$ but not the large disc inside $L$, and also does not lie in any other ellipse in $L$?

If $K$ and $L$ are not strictly convex (as in @WillSawin's example), we can always arrange so that $K'$ and $L$ have a common segment in their boundary and therefore no ellipse can be sandwiched.
